# React Native - How to deal with this

Tags: react-native

I'm a beginner and don't know how to go about it. I have a "state" collection and a sub-collection "city". The city has a people field with the amount of people. How to download the number of people in a city and display it in the country view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlw1O.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsGm9.png)

```
const getData = () => {
      firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('country')
        .onSnapshot(
           querySnapshot => {
            const countryData = [];
            let total = 0;
              querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

              countryData.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}); 


                firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .collection('country')
                .doc(doc.id)
                .collection('city')
                  .onSnapshot(
                     querySnapshot => {
                      const itemPeople = [];
                      let totalPeople = 0;
                        querySnapshot.forEach(doc2 => {
                           
                           totalPeople += doc2.data().people;
                           itemPeople.push({totalPeople});
                                   
                        });

                      setItemPeople(totalPeople);     
                        }, 
                 )
                  
              });
             
                   setCountryData(countryData);
                
              },
                error => {
                 console.log(error)
              }
          
        )
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      getData();
    }, []);
```

Comment: please edit your question and add pieces of code that is relevant to this question

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example how you can get the people value

```
const result = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("Country")
  .doc("your user's UID")
  .collection("City")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(queryDocumentSnapshot => {
      console.log(queryDocumentSnapshot.get("People"));
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    alert(err);
  });
```

Comment: I mean downloading from more cities as they will be in the database and transferring them to a flatlist with country names

Comment: Updated the answer Please check

Comment: I'll test it tonight and let you know if it worked

Comment: I did something like this but it doesn't quite work as it should, because it fetches data sums up but, sometimes it shows 2 or 3 countries, and 3 are entered.